# How to buy a lot of 65803 Technic plates for a mosaic project?

Tags: shopping, 3rd-party, mosaic

I would like to make a pixel-art mosaic and found out the existence of part 65803 for building the base board: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=65803#T=C

Alternately, there is a chinese clone available under the brand YNYNOO: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004221907158.html

My consideration to get a third-party part is because buying the genuine LEGO versions in bulk seems difficult. There are lots of suppliers on BrickLink, each one with a small inventory.

Is there any knowledge about the relative quality of the third-party equivalent? I guess it may be a tad lower than the genuine part, but the supplier is able to sell enough for my needs in one go.

I am looking for a solution with the least mental surcharge ( = reducing having to deal with a lot of suppliers) to buy the parts, and ideally not too expensive in shipping fees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Available as a Bestseller at LEGO Pick-and-Build. That means you can order a maximum of 999. Hopefully that is enough for your purposes.

https://www.lego.com/en-us/pick-and-build/pick-a-brick?query=65803

Comment: Interesting find!